# Bending non-regular arrows in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

I'm trying to create the following diagram in `tikz-cd` where the curved arrows are just straight lines instead of arrows.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    E \arrow[dash]{d}\arrow[bend left]{d}{D} \arrow[bend right]{dd}[swap]{G} &
 \q \arrow[dash]{d} \\
    E^D \arrow[dash]{d} & \q^D \arrow[dash]{d} \\
    K & \p
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

It seems that I can only enter `bend left` or `dash` as a parameter, but not both. Is there a way of achieving a curved line in `tikz-cd`?

Comment: Use comma: `[bend left,dashed]`

Comment: Ah of course! I should've tried that. Thanks

Comment: Note that the option for dashed lines is `dashed` not *dash*

Comment: @Sigur I'm aiming just to get a straight non-dashed arrowless line - the documentation seems to suggest that `dash` is correct

Comment: I see. You want a non arrowed line. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a more uniform syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}
\newcommand{\q}{\mathfrak{q}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
E \arrow[d,dash] \arrow[d,bend left,dash,"D"] \arrow[dd,bend right,dash,swap,"G"] &
   \q \arrow[d,dash] \\
E^D \arrow[d,dash] & \q^D \arrow[d,dash] \\
    K & \p
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

You simply specify all the features of an arrow in the same optional argument to `\arrow`. Note that the label should be specified as option between double quotes.

I'd have preferred giving the direction as a mandatory argument, but that's how the package author decided.

[image]

Comment: Why `\arrow[l]` does not work as expected (left arrow)?

Comment: @Sigur Works for me, provided it's in a cell where it makes sense.

Comment: ow, so sorry. I should sleep now. I'll not tell you what was my mistake. What a shame!